# Can you have a cell clear the data in it in Excel when a drop down option is picked?

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation

I would like for the cell with "10" in it to auto delete or clear the contents in the cell when I choose "Yes" from the drop down cell above it. Is there a function that I use or some kind of automation that would clear that cell when Yes is selected?

[Pic showing the excel setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mffDH.jpg)

Comment: Only one cell has 10 or may be more than one, and what about Drop down is in only one cell above cell 10 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Data Validation Cell is `E20`, and the number to clear is immediately below it, put this code in the *Worksheet* module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
If target = Range("E20") Then
    If target.Value = "Yes" And target.Offset(1, 0).Value = "10" Then
        target.ClearContents
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

(Right click the worksheet name -> View Code, and paste the above there)

Comment: I think one more check is required If YES and cell Value 10 then clear  10 from the Cell!

Comment: @RajeshS see edit

Comment: ,, yeah now added ,,+1 ☺